# Pre condition Select Form - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select

im about to create a select where i have a users table.
there will be 2 select where in the first select user must select the department and the next select must display all the names(firstname) that belongs to that department.

Views

```php
 <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" id="carOwnerDept" name='carOwnerDept'>
           @foreach ($internal as $internalsss)
                    <option value="{{ $internalsss }}">{{$internalsss}}</option>
           @endforeach
                </select>
                </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="carOwnerName" name='carOwnerName'>
           @foreach ($internals as $internalss)
                    <option value="{{ $internalss }}">{{$internalss}}</option>
           @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div>
```

Controller

```php
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $internal = Department::pluck('name');
        $internals = User::pluck('fname');
        $internalAudit = internalAudit::findOrFail($id);
        return view('Validation.validation',compact('internalAudit','internal','internals'));
    }
```

Comment: You want an dependent dropdown, right ??

Comment: you need to use ajax calls to load the second select right after the user's choice for the first select. unless you want to load all the names in your DB

Comment: Yeah exactly you're right !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975240/change-ajax-post-parameters-returned-html-based-on-alternating-dependant-dropd