# Laravel Backpack Filter Pre-populate dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have one dropdown by which I am populating the values, by using Laravel Backpack, but I have some other requirement, which is Populating another dropdown values based on a parent dropdown.

For an e.g If I Select State, Cities dropdown should have prepopulated values based on State Dropdown(`Select * from Cities where state_id = "selected_value"`)

```
$this->crud->addFilter([
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'code',
        'label' => 'Filter',
    ],
    function() {
        return Employee::select('code')->distinct()->get()->pluck('code', 'code')->toArray();
    },
    function($value) {
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'code', $value);
    });
```

I have added filter but here in select query,I want to get parent value of dropdown so that I can pass with `WHERE Clause`

Comment: In your frontend code, listen to the `change` event on the parent select element (i.e dropdown) and send an AJAX request to the backend with the value to filter by and then change the cities dropdown values accordingly on the success function of the AJAX request (using the response data)

Comment: you need to use ajax calls to load the second select right after the user's choice for the first select. unless you want to load all the names in your DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Ajax Post parameters & returned HTML based on alternating dependant dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975240/change-ajax-post-parameters-returned-html-based-on-alternating-dependant-dropd)

Comment: @CaddyDZ Just like we do it in normal PHP Code, will it work? Or Do I need to add some special things in Backpack? Although iin my filter I am doing proper searching, it is just prepopulated values